# How to find parameter value

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

**Situation:** I have a report that is based on a query. The query does not have any parameter values that need to be entered. Yet when I open the report, it asks me for Parameter Values.

**Question:** How can I find out for which part of the report Access needs these values?

I've been searching on the web, but all I can find are references to query parameters, which as I've said, I don't have.

Comment: Could be that a column name isn't right in the report. Make sure that the report and the query are consistent in their naming of objects.

Comment: as mentioned above comment. if its asking for a parameter, it will prompt the field name. Find out the field name and check the field..

Comment: I have managed to find one field that had a missing parameter. I did so by inputing "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" in the parameter field. This way it showed up clearly visible in the perview version of the report and I was able to identify it. I'm still fighting to get the other missing parameter though.

Comment: I have also checked the SQL Statement of the underlying query and nothing to be found their either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my missing parameters problem by using the following two strategies:

1. entered a fake variable ("XXXXXXXXXX") into the parameter, which I could then easily spot in the preview version of the report (once I realized which form it was, I realized that the particular form had a small light green triangle in the upper left hand corner indicating an error)
2. I used the database documenter to get object definitions for the report as well as the subreport that was included. In the report I saw that there was an expression that was included the report grouping function. this didn't show up anywhere else!

Hope this helps someone else!